# Confused Importing XML Into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import live daily sports odds into a google spreadsheet. I was using importhtml but I believe the website I was using has updated to XML. I like the simplicity of having it organized into a spreadsheet instead of having to go to the website, also helps me compare odds.

Can somebody please tell me what I need to do to import some data from the following website? Everything I have tried so far has failed.

More specifically, I need (by each matchup) the team names , the live scores/results, the current line and the moneyline. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

URL:
http://www.scoresandodds.com/gameDate/2019-11-08

Answer (score 0):

the site you trying to scrape runs fully on JavaScript so your only option is to try to find another site that hosts the same data because Google Sheets does not support scraping JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given site and generally what you will be left with is possible to be scraped:

[image: 0]